# ExtJS 4: assigning different stores to different instance of the same view?

Tags: extjs4

**Here's a brief overview of my app:**

I have an application where a container has 2 regions:

1. West -> treepanel
2. Center -> container with 'card' layout with 0 items.

Whenever a treenode is selected, my controller will check a my-own custom property called 'node_viewId' to see whether its value is undefined or not.

If it's undefined, it will create an instance of 'widget.myowngridpanel' (extend from 'gridpanel') and have it assigned with a unique store.
After that this instance will be added to the 'card' and have this instance as the active item so that it will be displayed in the center region.

**Why this setup?**

Each node represents different data that needs to be displayed on the same view and it needs to preserve the state of the view (e.g. in node A - user sorts 1st column and hides 2nd column and in node B - user sorts 3rd column and hides 1st column).

**My implementation:**

I almost got it to work but it didn't display the view quite correctly when switching different active item.

Here's the code in my controller (condensed version for example purpose):

```
this.control({
    '#treePanelID' : {
        itemclick : function(pThis, pRecord, pItem, pIndex, pE, pEOpts) {

        var newCenterView,newCenterViewId,newGridStore;
        if (pRecord.data.node_type === 'NodeA' && 
            pRecord.data.node_viewId === undefined) {

             newCenterView = Ext.create('widget.myowngridpanel',{
                                title:'GridPanel NodeA',
                    columns:[{ header: 'Node A item1', dataIndex: 'name'},
                                      {header: 'Node A item2', dataIndex: 'phone'}]
                                });

             newGridStore = Ext.create('NodeAStore');
             newCenterViewId = 'nodeAID';
        }
        else
        if (pRecord.data.node_type === 'NodeB' && 
            pRecord.data.node_viewId === undefined) {

             newCenterView = Ext.create('widget.myowngridpanel',{
                                title:'GridPanel NodeB',
                    columns:[{ header: 'Node B item1', dataIndex:
                                'address'},{header: 'Node B item2', dataIndex: 'city'},
                                { header: 'Node B item3', dataIndex: 'zipcode'}]});
             newGridStore = Ext.create('NodeBStore');
             newCenterViewId = 'nodeBID';
        }

       if(newCenterView !== undefined && 
          newCenterViewId !== undefined) {
            pRecord.data.node_viewId = newCenterView.itemId = newCenterViewId;
            this.getCenterCard().add(newCenterView);
            newCenterView.bindStore(newGridStore);
        }

        this.getCenterCard().getLayout().setActiveItem(pRecord.data.node_viewId);
```

**Here's a scenario to help your visualization of the issue:**

First, user selects 'node A', it goes to the 'nodeAID' view creation process.
You will see it shows as expected: title 'GridPanel NodeA' at the topBar and the grid with 1 header row that consists of these 2 columns: 'Node A item1' and 'Node A item2'.

Then, user selects 'node B', it goes to the 'nodeBID' view creation process.
Now here's the view issue comes up, you will see: title 'GridPanel NodeB' at the topBar and the grid with these 2 header rows with the following columns:

1) 'Node B item1','Node B item2','Node B item3'

2) 'Node A item1','Node A item2'

So for some reasons, the previous header columns from 'NodeAID' view exists in 'NodeBID' view as well.
What I found out so far is this issue happens due to the view creation through the alias (widget.myowngridpanel). When view creation is straight using 'Ext.grid.panel', it works perfectly.
But I need to be able to make it work with view creation through alias.

Please do let me know if I need to be more clear on my description.

Help!

**Update 04/23:**

There's an information regarding 'widget.myowngridpanel' that I didn't put because I thought it didn't have anything to do with the issue.
'widget.myowngridpanel' has dockedItems that consists of 2 buttons. When I remove it,
the issue disappears.
This is how I have the dockedItems:

```
dockedItems: [{
        xtype:'toolbar',
        height:'29px',
        dock:'top',
        items:[{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'Button 1',
            action:'button1pressed'
        },{
            xtype:'button', 
            text:'Button 2',
            action:'button2pressed'
        }]
     }]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add unique `stateId` property to each panel you're creating. This is used to save/restore grid configuration such as columns, order, position etc.

Comment: Hi Sha, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the issue still occurs after I tried it.

Comment: Are you sure? Try to delete cookies and try again. you might also want to check wether it's actually saving several different cookies for each panel

Comment: Yep just did like what you said and it's still a problem. By the way, I found out what's causing the issue; it was due to the dockeditems in my 'widget.myowngridpanel.' (Read my updated question in the 'Update 04/23' section). Still not sure why that's caused the issue though.

Comment: Can u post a screenshot with broken grid panels?

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to post img until I got more than 10 for my reputation :(  Bummer...